# How to create custom nested node tree in angular 5? I am a beginner in angular.I have no idea

Tags: tree, angular5

[image]

**"+" Button create new node and "Add Route" Button create sub node. Each node contains 2 drop down to select values.**

My sample response data look like this.

```
"flow":{  
         "children":{  
            "1":{  
               "children":{  

               },
               "data":{  
                  "id":"gbffhhjncjm"
               },
               "module":"device"
            },
            "2":{  
               "children":{  

               },
               "data":{  
                  "id":"fdjghmj"
               },
               "module":"device"
            },
            "4":{  
               "children":{  
                  "5":{  
                     "children":{  
                     },
                     "data":{  
                        "id":"jgjghfds"
                     },
                     "module":"device"
                  },
                  "6":{  
                     "children":{  

                     },
                     "data":{  
                        "id":"ghfgghfhhh"
                     },
                     "module":"device"
                  },
                  "7":{  
                     "children":{  
                        "8":{  
                           "children":{  

                           },
                           "data":{  
                              "id":"fgffhnhn"
                           },
                           "module":"play"
                        }
                     },
                     "data":{  
                        "id":"ghfhnvnn"
                     },
                     "module":"play"
                  }
               },
               "data":{  
                  "id":"sdgdgggf"
               },
               "module":"play"
            }
         },
}
```

**I need to figure out a nested tree structure with add new node, add sub node, remove node , drag and drop feature.**